# Highchart Columns - Space between columns not changing

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I know this topic is a bit recurrent here on Stackoverflow but after searching a lot of posts I haven't found a way to fix my issue.

I have a column chart that can have one or multiple columns.
The columns must have a fixed with and start from the left.
To be compliant with the client approved mockups, the space between columns must be 1.5times the width of each column.

I created a fiddle to replicate with I currently have.
I tried using pointPadding and groupPadding but unless I set the pointWidth the columns don't comply with the mockups.

How can I set the distance between columns?

Here's the current configuration:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
            maxPadding: 0,
            minPadding: 0,
            lineWidth: 0,
        tickWidth: 0,
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'],
        labels: {
            align: 'center',
            reserveSpace: true
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
            max: 399.71,
        lineWidth: 0,
        lineColor: 'transparent',        
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        minorGridLineWidth: 0,
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 77.28,
            color: '#A8AEB7',
            label: {
                x: 0,
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<span style=color:#616771;>Média</span><br/>77.28'
                },                
                align: 'left',
                style: {
                    color: '#A8AEB7'
                }
            },
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        backgroundColor: '#353C47',
        borderColor: '#353C47',
        shadow: false,
        style: {
            color: '#ffffff',
            fontSize: '10px'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
                pointWidth:25,
            pointPadding: 0,
            borderWidth: 0,
            borderRadius: 13,
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function() {    
                        this.series.chart.xAxis[0].labelGroup.element.childNodes[this.x].style='font-weight:bold';
                        },
                        mouseOut: function() {                 
                        this.series.chart.xAxis[0].labelGroup.element.childNodes[this.x].style='font-weight:normal';
                        }
                }
            }       
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [-48.54,279.92, -321.99,399.71]
    }]
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/marioandrade/L2u4pkxm/16/

In answer to Sebastian Wędzel comment.
The ideal layout would be something like this where the number of columns is dynamic, between 1 and 12, but always starting from the left, with the same spacing between columns as shown on the image. Adding empty or value zero columns is not acceptable for the client.

[image]

Comment: Could you share a picture of the result that you want to achieve?

Comment: Hey Sebastian, just added the picture you asked with a bit more information

Comment: would you like to achieve something like is done here? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vkw201em/

Comment: Thanks for the Help Sebastian. I managed to get to a possible solution thanks to your help. I'll be sharing it later.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments from Sebastian I managed to get to the following answer:

- On the xAxis I added a max value with the number of columns I want to show on the chart.
- Added the left property to push the xAxis to the right so it doesn't overlap the plotline
- Formatted the labels output of the xAxis so it only returns the values with the name of the months. Otherwise, even if the value was empty, it would return the number of the column.

```js
xAxis: { 
  left: 80,
  max: 6, 
  lineWidth: 0, 
  tickWidth: 0, 
  categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'], 
  labels: { 
    formatter: function() { 
      if(this.value.length > 2) { return this.value; } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

I created a fiddle with this implementation. Hope it can be helpful. https://jsfiddle.net/marioandrade/L2u4pkxm/29/

But please, if you have other possible solutions, share them.